# placing people in a row, where there are less people than there are spots

Tags: combinatorics

I have a particular type of combinatorics problem, that seems to be common, but i feel there is a bit more to this problem.
Here is the question:

> How many ways can 7 people be seated in a row of 9 chairs if Rob and Rhonda must sit next to each other for all possibilities.

I have seen people that have given answers to this problem, but almost everybody is getting a different answer.
I saw one solution that did it in 3 portions:

> 1) Rob-Rhonda connected + Rhonda-Rod connected:
>   = 8*2 = 16 ( I agree with this part)
>
> 2) Now removing Rob-Rhonda, we have 5 people left as well as 7 chairs left.
>   Now they say: 7C5 = 21
>   (This one i am not sure about, because all people must be in a row, so I ASSUME that means there cannot be empty seats between people) This 7-Choose-5, I don't think will place people in a row per se.
>
> 3)Then the solution says when we place people in the first chair, this first chair can have a choice of 5 people, then the next chair can have 4, etc.

So the overall answer would be the multiplication of these parts:

> (8*2) * 7C5 * 5! =  40 320.

Out of all the different solutions I have seen to this, I thought this might be the right one.

Hope someone here can explain this in more detail and/or tell me if this is correct answer or incorrect.

Comment: The solution seems correct. The problem does not specify the people themselves must all be in a row, it only says that the 9 chairs are in a row. Therefore, $\binom75$ is correct for part (2) of the explanation.

Comment: Yes, that is what i am having difficulty understanding the interpretation of the use of language here.  I just assume that when placing the people in a row of chairs, that the people will have to be side-by-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to arrive at the same answer.

First, wrap Rob and Rhonda with duct tape and replace them with a single "object".  Second, add two dummies to the group to fill the vacant chairs.  We now have $8$ objects in all, which can be arranged in $8!$ ways.  But we need to multiply by $2$ since the Rob-Rhonda pair can appear in either order, and we need to divide by $2$ because the two dummies are indistinguishable.  So the final number of arrangements is 
$$\frac{8! \times 2}{2} = 8! = 40,320$$

Comment: Hi awkward, this is really great! This idea of placing identical or indistinguishable dummies in this situation of trying to place number of people that is less than the number of seats is really a great way to do these problems.

Comment: Hi awkward,  I tried to replicate this way of placing identical dummies in the place of the spaces, but using a smaller set of object, and its not working out for me. I will set up a new question, and put the link here to see if you can show me where i would be going wrong with my analysis.

Comment: OK, actually I used a combinations formula, while you approached it from a permutations perspective. When I did it with permutations it did follow thru, both approaches.

Comment: Hi Awkward, I was hoping you could help explain something to me. The solution steps I have shown, it makes use of a combination in step 2, but overall it computes the number of arrangements, which is a permutation. Your approach used a "pure" permutation approach. So I am confused in terms of visualizing the problem solution properly that I have provided, the interplay between the combinations in step 2 and getting a permutation overall.

Comment: @Palu Your computation $7C5 * 5!$ gives the number of permutations of $7$ objects taken $5$ at a time, so you are effectively dealing with permutations.

Comment: Hi awkward, I was so focused on part 2, that I did not see that part2 + part3 would change the Combination to a Permutation. So i find it odd that the solution did not just put down the Permutation itself instead of doing it in 2 steps like this. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I will award this question to you awkward, for all your dedicated help here.